# How do I select from drop down menu with changing id on reload of webpage

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to select "802.11n" from drop down menu using selenium webdriver but "sbSelector_xxx" id is changed every time I reload the page.

```
<div id="RADIO_5GHz_adv" style="display: block;">
<table class="block" border="0">
<tbody>
   <tr>
   <tr id="show_80211Mode_5G">
      <th>
      <td>
         <div class="styled-select">
            <select id="80211Mode_5" onchange="ChangeWidthList('5')" name="80211Mode_5" sb="70855846" style="display: none;">
               <option value="802.11a">802.11a only</option>
               <option value="802.11n">802.11n only</option>
               <option value="802.11an">Mixed 802.11a/n</option>
               <option value="802.11ac">802.11ac only</option>
               <option value="802.11nac">Mixed 802.11n/ac</option>
               <option value="802.11anac">Mixed 802.11a/n/ac</option>
            </select>
            <div id="sbHolder_70855846" class="sbHolder" style="width:200px">
               <a id="sbToggle_70855846" class="sbToggle" href="#"></a>
               <a id="sbSelector_70855846" class="sbSelector" href="#" style="width:170px">802.11n only</a>
               <ul id="sbOptions_70855846" class="sbOptions" style="width: 200px; display: none;">
                  <li>
                     <a href="802.11a" rel="802.11a">802.11a only</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <a class="sbFocus" href="802.11n" rel="802.11n">802.11n only</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="802.11an" rel="802.11an">Mixed 802.11a/n</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="802.11ac" rel="802.11ac">802.11ac only</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="802.11nac" rel="802.11nac">Mixed 802.11n/ac</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="802.11anac" rel="802.11anac">Mixed 802.11a/n/ac</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
```

I am doing this in python using selenium webdriver. I want to select "802.11ac" option from drop down box using script automation.

HTML after I click on drop down box (using Firebug)

```
<div class="styled-select">
   <select id="80211Mode_5" onchange="ChangeWidthList('5')" name="80211Mode_5" sb="99213187" style="display: none;">
      <option value="802.11a">802.11a only</option>
      <option value="802.11n">802.11n only</option>
      <option value="802.11an">Mixed 802.11a/n</option>
      <option value="802.11ac">802.11ac only</option>
      <option value="802.11nac">Mixed 802.11n/ac</option>
      <option value="802.11anac">Mixed 802.11a/n/ac</option>
   </select>
   <div id="sbHolder_99213187" class="sbHolder" style="width:200px">
      <a id="sbToggle_99213187" class="sbToggle sbToggleOpen" href="#"></a>
      <a id="sbSelector_99213187" class="sbSelector" href="#" style="width:170px">802.11n only</a>
      <ul id="sbOptions_99213187" class="sbOptions" style="width: 200px; top: 30px; max-height: 151.4px; display: block;">
         <li>
            <a class="" href="802.11a" rel="802.11a">802.11a only</a>
         </li>
         <li>
         <li>
         <li>
         <li>
         <li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

only visibility of  tag changes when I click on drop down box.

Comment: When your drop down getting visible??..here as showing drop down style="display: none;"

Comment: It becomes visible after I click on drop down box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is multiple ways you can do this. 1 way is by using the classname of the selector.

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('sbSelector')
```

If you don't want to do it by class name or it isn't unique you can still use the ID by checking if it contains sbSelector_ using Xpath.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@id, "sbSelector_")'])
```

Ofcourse you could also check for the text of the element that should contain 802.11n

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "802.11n")]')
```

**Edit** Added way to click on the hidden element

The element you are trying to click on is inside this element:

```
<select id="80211Mode_5" onchange="ChangeWidthList('5')" name="80211Mode_5" sb="31295123" style="display: none;">
```

Note the style="display: none;". This means the element is not displayed on the page. This is why Selenium won't be able to click on this element and will throw an ElementNotVisibleException. This is to prevent you from clicking on elements that a user normally won't be able to click on aswell. If you are persistent on clicking this hidden element you could execute a javascript command that will do it for you.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('sbSelector')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

**Edit 2**
To get all your a elements use this:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul[class='sbOptions'] > li > a")
for element in elements:
    # Do stuff with the elements in your list
```

Comment: I have following code in my scrips
       driver.find_element_by_id("logIn_btn").click()
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Wireless").click()
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#RADIO_5GHz > div.advButton").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@id, "sbSelector_")]').click()

But it's throwing following error:

Traceback
  File "bb", line 27, in test_bb
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@id, "sbSelector_")]').click()
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: @ManojTyagi This means you are trying to click an element that is not currently visible on the page. You could try added a webdriverwait with an expected condition to wait for it to become clickable. However this might not work depending on wether the element becomes visible or not. Verify that the element you're trying to click is visible on the page.

Comment: No matter how much I put it to wait, it still throws ElementNotVisibleException exception.

Comment: @YogeshTyagi See the edit in that answer I've just made

Comment: It doesn't throw ElementNotVisibleException for drop down box now but how do I select second/third option from drop down box?

Comment: @YogeshTyagi you can use driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sbSelector') and it will return a list instead of a single element. Now you can iterate over this list

Comment: I have updated the html showing drop down options available. I want to select "802.11ac" from drop down option.

Comment: @YogeshTyagi Check the second edit, This will get the a tag from all list items in sbSelector list

Comment: None of the element in elements is "Visible". I added this code

for element in elements:
                if element.is_displayed():
                        print "Element is displayed"

"Element is displayed" is never printed.

Comment: That's because the element isn't displayed like I explained in my first edit.

Comment: Then how do I select it if it's not displayed?

Comment: @YogeshTyagi By using the driver.execute_script() method I metioned in my first edit

Comment: How do I select option  "Mixed 802.11a" from drop down after I have elements from:
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul[class='sbOptions'] > li > a")

Comment: You can either make sure the dropdown is visible by opening it first by clicking on the element the user would click on to open the dropdown, or you could try using iterating over the elements and using  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element) on the "Mixed 802.11a" element

Comment: only display of <ul\> tag changes to " display: block" after I click on drop down box. I have updated the HTML

Comment: @YogeshTyagi So you can use something like driver.find_element_by_class_name('sbOptions').click() to open the dropdown and after this you can use the code you already have to locate the element you need and click on it as it should be visible now

Comment: If I do this I get ElementNotVisibleException and moreover there are so many other elements with class name "sbOptions".

Comment: @YogeshTyagi than you should figure out a better locator that is unique. I don't know your website so I'm just doing it on what I can see.

Comment: If I change the visibilty of <select id="80211Mode_5" onchange="ChangeWidthList('5')" name="80211Mode_5" sb="70855846" style="display: none;"> to "display:block" it see a new drop down box like this -> [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/jz3vj3tz2vi3k32/Screenshot%20from%202016-06-01%2019%3A41%3A56.png?dl=0)
But I have to select from the default drop down box on webpage.

Comment: I have put the complete HTML file here [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/bmfigttjgo1i78l/a.html?dl=0)

Comment: It's working. I did following

        driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('sbOptions')[11].style.display='inline-block';")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='802.11ac']").click()

Thanks @RemcoW for you help and patience -:)

Comment: @YogeshTyagi Nice glad you got it working. Please accept my answer if it helped you